# Pandas columns to rows transformation not working?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

We have below  pandas dataframe

[image]

and we need to convert into below dataframe

[image]

while using pd.wide_to_long command we are getting below error:-

```
ValueError: stubname can't be identical to a column name
```

This command is being use:-

```
pd.wide_to_long(df,['Org','City'],i=['First Name','Middle Name','Last Name','Years'],j='drop').reset_index(level=[0,1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me your solution working, also added parameter `stubnames`. Mayb eit is bug in oldier pandas version, [link](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22468), so you can try to upgrade pandas to last version:

```
df = pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['Org','City'],
                     i=['First Name','Middle Name','Last Name','Years'],
                     j='drop').reset_index().drop('drop', 1)
print (df)
  First Name Middle Name Last Name  Years  Org City
0         aa          cc        dd   2019    v    n
1         aa          cc        dd   2019    m    m
2         aa          cc        dd   2019    d    n
3         aa          cc        dd   2019    p    j
4         zz          yy        xx   2018    p    n
5         zz          yy        xx   2018    q    n
6         zz          yy        xx   2018    i    d
7         zz          yy        xx   2018  NaN  NaN
```

EDIT: If possible some duplicates in data is possible create default index by `reset_index` and add column `index` to `i` variables:

```
print (df)
  First Name Middle Name Last Name  Years Org0 Org1 Org2 Org3 City0 City1  \
0         aa          cc        dd   2019    v    m    d    p     n     m   
1         zz          yy        xx   2018    p    q    i  NaN     n     n   

  City2 City3  
0     n     j  
1     d   NaN  

df = pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), stubnames=['Org','City'],
                     i=['index','First Name','Middle Name','Last Name','Years'],
                     j='drop').reset_index().drop(['drop', 'index'], 1)
print (df)
  First Name Middle Name Last Name  Years  Org City
0         aa          cc        dd   2019    v    n
1         aa          cc        dd   2019    m    m
2         aa          cc        dd   2019    d    n
3         aa          cc        dd   2019    p    j
4         zz          yy        xx   2018    p    n
5         zz          yy        xx   2018    q    n
6         zz          yy        xx   2018    i    d
7         zz          yy        xx   2018  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael, but if we need to stubname more than 2 columns then we get an error  
stubname can't be identical to a column name

Comment: @Amol - Can you be more specific?

Comment: please refer this question :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59267419/how-to-resolve-wide-to-long-error-in-pandas

Comment: Getting error , when we have large dataset like 18000(rows)* 71(columns)
Error :: ValueError: the id variables need to uniquely identify each row,
and above code working for small dataset

Comment: its working for small dataset, and for large dataset still getting same error

Comment: @Amol - Data are confidental?

Comment: @Amol - Then hard to help :( Only if is possible anonymize data.

Comment: I Guess its indexing problem :
ValueError: the id variables need to uniquely identify each row

Comment: @Amol - One idea - `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)` before my solution should help

Comment: Thank you @ jezrael for your valuable help,
Got it, We have duplicate records so we are getting above error
so before applying pd.wide_to_long , we need to check and remove duplicates in our dataframe