# How to resolve wide_to_long error in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have following dataframe
[image]
And I want to convert it into the following format:-
[image]

To do so I have used the following code snippet:-

```
df = pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['manufacturing_unit_','outlet_','inventory','year'],i=['Brand','customer name','Factory'],j='drop').reset_index().drop('drop', 1)
```

But we are getting below errors::

```
1) ValueError: stubname can't be identical to a column name
2) the id variables need to uniquely identify each row
```

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use numpy [`concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) like that:

```
res = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.concatenate([df.iloc[:,[0,1,2,3,6,9,12]], df.iloc[:,[0,1,2,4,7,10,13]], df.iloc[:,[0,1,2,5,8,11,14]]]))
res.columns = ['Brand', 'customer name', 'Factory', 'manufacturing', 'outlet', 'inventory', 'year']
```

**Update** for variable number of column names (e.g. 1...3):

```
cols = [f'Brand|customer name|Factory|{x}$' for x in range(1,4)]
pd.DataFrame(pd.np.concatenate([df.filter(regex=col) for col in cols]))
```

Comment: But what if my no of columns are not fixed!

Comment: Please see my update answer. This works for a variable  number of variable columns up to 9. If you have more you'll have to adapt the regex accordingly.